# Update Access front end through batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ms-access

Looking to see if there would be a way for users to update their MS Access db front end by clicking a button.  The button would then trigger a batch file that would grab the file from a location on our server, and overwrite the current db on the users local PC.   All done within one office, so network addresses would be all the same.

Location of file to copy: 10.0.0.0.5/Data/DB/Database.accdb
Location of file to overwrite:  c:\DB\Database.accdb

Any ideas?  Ideally  I would love for someone to write a nice exe file that deletes the older version and installs the newer version, but can't write that kind of code.

Comment: Batch files are not EXE files.  A batch file is a script that is interpreted at run time.  If you want to copy a file, that is one line of code in a batch file. `copy "\\10.0.0.0.5\Data\DB\Database.accdb" "c:\DB\"`

Comment: I used to use code to copy updated frontend until IT tightened user permissions and code can no longer copy/save files. Review https://forums.aspfree.com/microsoft-access-help-18/mutiple-users-recordset-issue-323364.html

Comment: Thanks.... I know the difference between .bat and .exe files.  My comment reflects my ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Write a batch file to retrieve the newer version of the front end from it's source and copy it into the folder where the user's copy of the front end file lives. Add a line at the end of the batch file to launch msacess.exe with the filename of your front end program as a [command line parameter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6#ID0EAABAAA=Access).

The batch file can be located anywhere, but I recommend locating it in the folder where your application front end will reside.

Create a Windows shortcut to the batch file, which can be placed on the users' Desktop or anywhere else the user expects to launch the application.

Bonus points for dressing up the shortcut to the batch file by changing the icon: Right-click|Properties|Change icon... button.

Answer (score 1):

A nice article on the topic can be found here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

It uses neither a bat, nor an exe, but a *VBscript*:

```
Option Explicit

' Launch script for PPT test/development/operation.
' Version 1.3.0
' 2013-09-15
' Cactus Data. Gustav Brock

Const DESKTOP = &H10
Const LOCALAPPDATA = &H1C

Dim objFSO
Dim objAppShell
Dim objDesktopFolder
Dim objLocalAppDataFolder
Dim objLocalFolder
Dim objRemoteFolder

Dim strLocalFolder
Dim strRemoteFolder
Dim strDesktopFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataDsgFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder
Dim strDsgSubfolder
Dim strPptSubfolder
Dim strPptAppSubfolder
Dim strPptNcSuffix
Dim strAppName
Dim strAppSuffix
Dim strShortcutName
Dim strAppLocalPath
Dim strAppLocalBackPath
Dim strAppRemotePath
Dim strShortcutLocalPath
Dim strShortcutRemotePath
Dim strRegPath
Dim strRegKey
Dim strRegValue
Dim booNoColour

Dim varValue


' Adjustable parameters.
strDsgSubfolder = "DSG"
strPptSubfolder = "PPT"
strPPtNcSuffix = "NC"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Uncomment one folder name only:
'strPptAppSubfolder = "Development"
strPptAppSubfolder = "Operations"
'strPptAppSubfolder = "Test"
' ---------------------------------
' Indicate if the script is for the normal version (0) or the no-colour version (1):
booNoColour = 0
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strRemoteFolder = "K:\_Shared\Sales Planning\Environments\" & strPptAppSubfolder
If booNoColour = 1 Then
  strAppSuffix = strPptNcSuffix
Else
  strAppSuffix = ""
End If
strAppName = "SalesPlanningTool" & strAppSuffix & ".accdb"
If strPptAppSubfolder = "Operations" Then
  If strAppSuffix = "" Then
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT.lnk"
  Else
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strAppSuffix & ".lnk"
  End If
Else
  If strAppSuffix = "" Then
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strPptAppSubfolder & ".lnk"
  Else
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strAppSuffix & " " & strPptAppSubfolder & ".lnk"
  End If
End If

' Enable simple error handling.
On Error Resume Next

' Find user's Desktop and AppData\Local folder.
Set objAppShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objDesktopFolder = objAppShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
strDesktopFolder = objDesktopFolder.Self.Path
Set objLocalAppDataFolder = objAppShell.Namespace(LOCALAPPDATA)
strLocalAppDataFolder = objLocalAppDataFolder.Self.Path

' Dynamic parameters.
strLocalAppDataDsgFolder = strLocalAppDataFolder & "\" & strDsgSubfolder
strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder = strLocalAppDataDsgFolder & "\" & strPptSubfolder
strLocalFolder = strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder & "\" & strPptAppSubfolder
strAppLocalPath = strLocalFolder & "\" & strAppName
strShortcutLocalPath = strDesktopFolder & "\" & strShortcutName

' Permanent parameters.
strAppRemotePath = strRemoteFolder & "\" & strAppName
strShortcutRemotePath = strRemoteFolder & "\" & strShortcutName

' Create the File System Object.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strRemoteFolder) Then
  Call ErrorHandler("No access to " & strRemoteFolder & ".")
Else
  Set objRemoteFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strRemoteFolder)
  ' If local folder does not exist, create the folder.
  If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder) Then
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalAppDataDsgFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalAppDataDsgFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalAppDataDsgFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalAppDataDsgPPtFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strLocalFolder)
End If

If Not objFSO.FileExists(strAppRemotePath) Then
  Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppRemotePath & vbCrLF & "could not be found.")
Else
  ' Close a running PPT.
  Call KillTask("PPT")
  ' Wait while TaskKill is running twice to close the instance(s) of PPT and PPT Background.
  Call AwaitProcess("taskkill.exe")
  Call KillTask("PPT Background")
  ' Wait while TaskKill is running twice to close the instance(s) of PPT and PPT Background.
  Call AwaitProcess("taskkill.exe")

  ' Copy app to local folder.
  If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strAppLocalPath)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
      Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppName & vbCrLF & "can not be refreshed/updated. It may be in use.")
    End If
  End If
  If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
    Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppLocalPath & vbCrLF & "could not be replaced.")    
  Else
    objFSO.CopyFile strAppRemotePath, strAppLocalPath
    If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
      Call ErrorHandler("Application could not be copied to " & strLocalFolder & ".")
    End If
    ' Create copy for PPT Background.
    strAppLocalBackPath = Replace(Replace(strAppLocalPath, ".accdb", ".accbg"), "SalesPlanningTool", "SalesPlanningToolBack")
    objFSO.CopyFile strAppLocalPath, strAppLocalBackPath
    If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
      Call ErrorHandler("Background application could not be copied to " & strLocalFolder & ".")
    End If
  End If

  ' Copy shortcut.
  objFSO.CopyFile strShortcutRemotePath, strShortcutLocalPath
  If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
    Call ErrorHandler("Shortcut could not be copied to your Desktop.")
  End If
End If

' Write Registry entries for Access security.
strRegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\"
strRegValue = "VBAWarnings"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = 1
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue,"REG_DWORD")

strRegKey = strRegKey & "Trusted Locations\LocationLocalAppData\"
strRegValue = "AllowSubfolders"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = 1
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_DWORD")

strRegValue = "Date"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = Now
varValue = FormatDateTime(varValue, vbShortDate) & " " & FormatDateTime(varValue, vbShortTime)
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

strRegValue = "Description"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = "Local AppData"
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

strRegValue = "Path"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = strLocalAppDataFolder & "\"
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

' Run PPT.
If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
  Call RunApp(strAppLocalPath, False)
Else
  Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppLocalPath & vbCrLF & "could not be found.")    
End If

Set objRemoteFolder = Nothing
Set objLocalFolder = Nothing
Set objLocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
Set objDesktopFolder = Nothing
Set objAppShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

WScript.Quit


' Supporting subfunctions
' -----------------------

Sub RunApp(ByVal strFile, ByVal booBackground)

  Dim objShell
  Dim intWindowStyle

  ' Open as default foreground application.
  intWindowStyle = 1

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34), intWindowStyle, False
  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub KillTask(ByVal strWindowTitle)

  Dim objShell

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "TaskKill.exe /FI ""WINDOWTITLE eq " & strWindowTitle & """", 7, False
  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub AwaitProcess(ByVal strProcess)

  Dim objSvc
  Dim strQuery
  Dim colProcess
  Dim intCount

  Set objSvc = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
  strQuery = "select * from win32_process where name='" & strProcess & "'"

  Do 
    Set colProcess = objSvc.Execquery(strQuery)
    intCount = colProcess.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
      WScript.Sleep 300
    End If
  Loop Until intCount = 0

  Set colProcess = Nothing
  Set objSvc = Nothing

End Sub


Sub WriteRegistry(ByVal strRegPath, ByVal varValue, ByVal strRegType)
  ' strRegType should be: 
  '   "REG_SZ" for a string
  '   "REG_DWORD" for an integer
  '   "REG_BINARY" for a binary or boolean
  '   "REG_EXPAND_SZ" for an expandable string

  Dim objShell

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Call objShell.RegWrite(strRegPath, varValue, strRegType)

  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub ErrorHandler(Byval strMessage)

  Set objRemoteFolder = Nothing
  Set objLocalFolder = Nothing
  Set objLocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
  Set objDesktopFolder = Nothing
  Set objAppShell = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  WScript.Echo strMessage
  WScript.Quit

End Sub
```

You could probably convert it to *PowerShell*, which I would use today.

Answer (score 0):

I use a vbscript for that purpose. I only update the path for the file due to be copied and then I sent an email to the users with a link to the script. The user clicks the link and the script is executed.

Copy the code below to a text file and save it as .vbs. Don't forget to set the path for the file due to be copied.

```
Option Explicit
Call Main()

Private Sub Main()

    const folderFrom = "\\Somepath\Somefolder\"     'Folder: Must supply backslash
    const fileName = "SomeFile.accdb"               'File name with extension
    const overwrite = -1                            'OverWrite = True

    'Ask user to proceed
    dim msg
    msg = "The script will copy the file below to your desktop. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          String(75,"_") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "File: " & " " & " " & " " & " " & " " & " " & " '" & fileName & "' " & vbNewLine & _
          "Folder: " & " " & " '" & folderFrom & "' " & vbNewLine & _
          String(75,"_") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Proceed?"
    if MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "FileCopy Confirmation") = vbNo then exit sub

    on error resume next
    dim filesys
    set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'File exists in folder?
    if not filesys.FileExists(folderFrom & fileName) then
        MsgBox "File not found. Task aborted. ", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Attention:"
        exit sub
    end if

    'User's desktop path
    dim desktopPath
    desktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"

    'Copy file
    filesys.CopyFile folderFrom & fileName, desktopPath & fileName, overwrite

    'Validate file copied
    if filesys.FileExists(desktopPath & fileName) then
        Msgbox "File copied successfully.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Success!"
    else
        MsgBox "File could not be copied... ", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Copy Failed..."
    end if
End Sub
```

Suggestion:

You shouldn't overwrite the existing front-end database but instead you should consider versioning e.g. v2.0, v2.1, v2.2 etc. for better tracking.